# Trying to program four fours in prolog

Tags: prolog

Trying to solve the four fours program using prolog.  Not sure where to begin.  It is similar to the 1996 math problem.  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180223180548/http://mathforum.org/ruth/1996.puzzle.html)  I can do it in C, but can't figure out how to get it to prolog.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to begin?

EDIT:
So far given a list of possible numbers [44,4,0.4,infinity(0.4)]  I can come up with combinations that lead to having four 4s (i.e. [44,44], [4,4,4,4], etc)

Now I need to figure out how to apply various operators to get to possible equations.

Comment: FYI, this will probably be closed as being to broad. You need to ask a specific question. SO isn't a site to request tutorials/general tips.

Comment: Search for solutions to other puzzles in Prolog. Look into using clpfd. Probably if you code your equations with clpfd you'll be halfway there.

Comment: the link is dead now and your description is incomprehensible on its own. start by writing a solution in pseudocode, in English even.